# How to write Procedure for delete and update query simultaneously in MySql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `ATTR_ID` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    `BRICK_CODE` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ATTR_ID`, `BRICK_CODE`),
)

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateAttributeCode(IN brickCode DOUBLE, IN attrId DOUBLE ) 
BEGIN
 select * from product a where a.BRICK_CODE=brickCode
 INSERT INTO product(ATTR_ID,BRICK_CODE) VALUES (20000043, 10007026);
END

call UpdateAttributeCode(10007026,200)
```

Comment: Your published code doesn't bear much relationship to the title - can you clarify what you are trying to do please.

Comment: I added table definition and i want to update all attribute values(m) associated with brick code(1). for that, I want to create a procedure. could u share any other idea.

Comment: You could clarify this question by adding sample data from product before and after the procedure is called. Also using double as a datatype for these columns is probably a bad idea given ' FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html